# Conditionally apply properties to an array or object, but only if the properties already exist

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm wondering if there's any PHP "standard" way to apply properties to an object or array, but only if they exist. Array example

```
$prototypeConfig = array(
    "username" => null,
    "password" => null,
    "email" => null
);

$receivedConfig = array(
    "username" => "test",
    "password" => "123",
    "email" => "foo@example.com",
    "nonexisting" => true
);

$config = some_magic_array_function($prototypeConfig, $receivedConfig);

print_r($config);

// Result would be:
// "username" => "test",
// "password" => "123",
// "email" => "foo@example.com"
```

```

Basically that magic array function should throw away all properties or keys which aren't existing in the prototype. Of course, I can easily implement an own function which does that, but probably there's a PHP function which does exactly that.

**ExtJS** has the [Ext.applyIf](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext-method-applyIf) method to do exactly that, but I'm missing a PHP counterpart, if such one exists.

Comment: I don't think there is anything there by default, but it's [very easy to implement](http://ideone.com/pq7gdS). A similar algorithm would work for objects.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that it is easy to implement in the question, my question was if there's a standard way of doing it.